# sorting a dictionary key based on values after they are converted to integers

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary such as `mydict={'tom': '100','dick': '50','harry': '121','jim':'25'}`. Notice how the values are numbers in string format.
i wrote a function to sort the keys based on values in descending order

```
def sortfunc(dict_arg):
    return sorted(dict_arg.keys(),key=dict_arg.get,reverse=True)
```

So my output should be `['harry','tom','dick','jim']` since 'harry' has the highest value of 121 and jim has the lowest value of 25.
but i get `['dick','jim','harry','tom']` because the values are asciibetically ordered.Now i need to figure out a way to to convert the values to integers and sort the keys by the values which are converted to integers. Any hints to nudge me in the right direction are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a lambda function here, to convert the values to int

```
mydict={'tom': '100','dick': '50','harry': '121','jim':'25'}
print sorted(mydict, key = lambda k: int(mydict[k]), reverse = True)
```

**Output**

```
['harry', 'tom', 'dick', 'jim']
```

Comment: SO is the use of lambda the only way to do it clean?... just wishful thinking to do it by say key=mydict.get(int).... thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @thefoutheye I guess you are right. I do not want to over complicate things by giving up readability. Thanks.